# NCG with all noncommutativity in a nilpotent ideal

Tags: noncommutative-geometry, noncommutative-algebra

While in general non-commutative geometry behaves rather differently from commutative geometry when it comes to local-to-global properties (descent), there are versions of "mild" noncommutative geometry that behave very much like commutative geometry in this respect. The archetypical example here is supergeometry.

One may argue that the reason that the theory of supergeometry proceeds in close analogy with ordinary differential geometry is simply because a supercommutative algebra is just a commutative algebra, but internal to a nontrivially braided symmetric monoidal category. On the other hand when it comes to local properties and the fact that Grothendieck topologies work well in supergeometry, this is to do more specifically with the fact that the non-commutativity is all in the nilpotent ideals of supercommutative superalgebras, and hence irrelevant to coverings and descent.

This leads one to wonder whether there is something to be gained in developing a geometry based on formal duals to those noncommutative algebras for which "all the noncommutativity is in the nilpotent ideals", e.g. such that when quotienting out the maximal two-sided nilpotent ideal they become commutative. Supergeometry would be a special case of this, but it would be more general.

Has anything like this been investigated somewhat systematically anywhere? Is there any names attached to this that one could search for to find more?

Comment: what are other examples of such NCGs?

Comment: Cross posted from MSE http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1214990/ncg-with-all-noncommutativity-in-a-nilpotent-ideal

Comment: @bananastack: a natural class of examples is provided by truncations of the homotopy groups of a connective $E_n$ ring spectrum, $n \ge 2$ (e.g. the "group algebra" $\mathbb{S}[\Omega^n X]$ of the $n$-fold loop space of a space). Studying the noncommutative geometry of these things should be an approximation to studying "$E_n$ algebraic geometry" itself.

Comment: In line with Qiaochu's comment, some aspects of E_n-geometry are studied in the [thesis of John Francis](http://math.northwestern.edu/~jnkf/writ/thezrev.pdf) and [this sequel](http://math.northwestern.edu/~jnkf/writ/cotangentcomplex.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, excellent. I suppose I should have been aware of this. The thesis in chapter 4 has just what I have been after here. Did anyone have any substantial thoughts on the perspective of regarding this as generalized supergeometry?  For instance Deligne's theorem http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Deligne+theorem+on+tensor+categories is suggesting higher versions with symmetric monoidal 1-categories replaced by symmetric monoidal (oo,n)-categories. Deligne finds that supergroups are the Tannakian dual for n=1 (subject to a nicety condition). Can one find "E_n-groups" as the dual in the higher case?

Comment: Well, I suppose a crucial difference of supergeometry is that the grading group is finite cyclic. Any thoughts on that in the E_n conext or more generally in the context of the above question?

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but by analogy with _"supercommutative algebra is just a commutative algebra, but internal to a nontrivially braided symmetric monoidal category"_, could one take an "any-commutative algebra" to be a commutative algebra that is internal to a braided symmetric monoidal category whose braiding corresponds to [anyonic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anyon) exchange symmetry, as opposed to fermionic exchange symmetry? If such an algebraic category exists, its opposite might describe the geometry of anyon configurations.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: me not too good with spectra, could you unpack your comment a little? eg, what's the group algebra?

Comment: Sorry, I was being silly. I guess after passing to homotopy groups you just get a (graded) commutative ring. @bananastack: the group algebra is the thing it has to be, namely the left adjoint to the forgetful functor from $E_n$ spectra to $E_n$ spaces given by taking the space of units $\text{GL}_1$ (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/infinity-group+of+units). This construction appears, for example, in Waldhausen K-theory (for $n = 1$), as well as in Snaith's theorem (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Snaith+theorem) (for $n = \infty$).

Answer (score 5):

Lieven le Bruyn kindly points out

- M. Kapranov, *Noncommutative geometry based on commutator expansions*, J. reine und angew. Math. 505 (1998), 73-118, [math.AG/9802041](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9802041)

which develops pretty much exactly the idea that I was asking about. With that in hand, Google tells me to my surprise that my own wiki had a hidden entry on this all along

- *[nLab -- Kapranov's noncommutative geometry](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Kapranov%27s+noncommutative+geometry)*

which Zoran Škoda once started, thankfully. This has a few more links. Good stuff.